# R - How to find the best input variables from a list to maximize function output without for loops

Tags: r, performance, loops

I have a function `myFunction<-function(var1,var2)` which uses two input variables (`var1`and `var2`) and after a few calculations steps returns a result (this result is obtained after running a few regressions). My two input variables have limited possible values (they can only be chosen in a list of 20 integers named `myList`, and `var2`must be greater than `var1`).

My goal is to find the best combination possible of `var1`and `var2`to maximize the output of my function (which is always positive). I already have an answer with two `for`loops where I try all the possible combinations but it isn't very fast and not R-like.

Is there a more effective way to find the best `var1`and `var2`to maximise the result of `myFunction`?

At this time my solution with `for`loops is like this :

```
myList<-c(5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55,60,75,80,90,105,120,135,150,165,180)
bestVar1<-0;bestVar2<-0;bestResult<-0
for (i in myList[(1:length(myList))-1] {
    otherList<-myList[which(myList>i)]
    for (j in otherList){
        temp<-myFunction(i,j)
        if (temp>bestResult) {bestResult<-temp;bestVar1<-i;bestVar2<-j}
    }
}
bestVar1;bestVar2;bestResult # to know the results
```

**EDIT : `myFunction`**

the expression of `myFunction` is something like that:

```
myFunction<-function(var1,var2){
    columnVar1<-df[,paste0('d',var1);columnVar2<-df[,paste0('d',var2]
    column_2Var1<-df4[,paste0('d',var1);column_2Var2<-df4[,paste0('d',var2] 
    df2<-cbind(df2,columnVar1,columnVar2)
    df3<-cbind(df3,column_2Var1,column_2Var2)
    reg<-lm(x1~.,data=df2)
    result<-predict(reg,df3)
}
```

So basically I have two dataframes `df`and `df4` with 20 columns each (one for each possible value of `myList`, they are Moving Average of the order of `myList`), and two other dataframes `df2`and `df3`. I run a regression on `df2` with the 2 new columns and then I predict those results on `df3`. I just want to find the best order of moving averages to have the best predicted value. I simplified a bit the content of `myFunction`but that's the idea.

Comment: is myFunction a black box or you have its expression?

Comment: It indeed depends on your function call. It it is in principle continuous (despite the use of discrete input choices) there might be gradient methods available, but if it's about a faster way for performing extensive search, you  might think about vectorizing the steps...
Maybe if you are more explicit about what you mean by 'effective' also, there might be other help to your problem.

Comment: by 'effective' I mostly mean the fastest way possible

Answer (score 0):

Your way is not that bad, if (as I suppose) `myFunction` is not vectorized. The following way might be more `R`-ish, but not more efficient:

```
myFunWrap<-function(x) myFunction(x[1],x[2])
max(apply(combn(myList,2),2,myFunWrap))
```